# Sikuli get part of a filepath - Split string

Tags: python, string, jython, sikuli, sikuli-x

I want to get a number from the filepath of the current file in Sikuli - Jython

I have a python example of what i'm trying to achive.

In the example the path is:
C:\PycharmProjects\TestingPython\TestScripts\TestScript_3.sikuli\TestScript.py

```
import os

PointerLeft = "Script_"
PointerRight = ".sikuli"

FilePath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
NumberIWant = FilePath[FilePath.index(PointerLeft) + len(PointerLeft):FilePath.index(PointerRight)]

print(NumberIWant)
```

So what i want to get is the number 3. In python the example above works, but I cant use the `__file__` ref in Sikulix. Nor does the split of the string work, so even if I get the string of the path, I still have to get the number.

Any help and/or ideas is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important:
the `.py` file in a `.sikuli` folder must have the same name
hence in your case: `...\TestScript_3.sikuli\TestScript_3.py`

It looks like you are trying to run your stuff in the `PyCharm`context. If you do not run the script in the SikuliX IDE, you have to add `from sikuli import *` even to the main script.

To get the file path of the script use `getBundlePath()`.

Then `os.path(getBundlePath()).basename()` will result to the string `"TestScript_3.sikuli"`.

RaiMan from SikuliX

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the nameing convention of the file-folders.

The: `os.path(getBundlePath()).basename()` gives me an error

The error: **AttributeError ( 'unicode' object has no attribute 'basename' )**

Comment: Oh, figured it out. I just said `os.path.basename(getBundlePath())` and got the output you predicted.